# Is automatic update of React's context usual behavior?

Tags: reactjs

I thought that context acts in a similar way as state so I've created function `handleUpdate` that can update `state` which is context using as a value. Afterwards I've noticed that context is being updated without triggering `handleUpdate`.

Provider:

```
<DashboardContext.Provider value={{dashboard:this.state,handleChange:this.handleChange}}>
   {/*...*/}
</DashboardContext.Provider>
```

handleChange function

```
handleChange=(what, value)=> this.setState({[what]:value});
```

In another component which uses context: this triggers updating of context **without** calling `handleUpdate`.

```
let updatedTasks = this.context.dashboard.tasks;
updatedTasks[task.id] = {/* ... something */};
```

Afterwards it changes context value and parents state (which is context using) without calling `setState`. Is this usual behavior? I though that all states should be handled with `setState` function.

As the actual workaround to lose reference on contexts object I've used:

```
let updatedTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.context.dashboard.tasks));
```

but it doesn't seems like a correct solution for me.

**Edit: as @Nicholas Tower suggested solution:**
my current code

State in constructor now looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  value: {
     dashboard: {
    // everything from state is now here
     },
     handleChange: this.handleChange,
  }
};
```

I pass state.value instead of custom object now

```
<DashboardContext.Provider value={this.state.value}>
         {/*...*/}
</DashboardContext.Provider>
```

but still when I do this, context and state (both) are being updated without calling handleChange

```
let updatedTasks = this.context.dashboard.tasks;
updatedTasks[task.id] = {/* ... something */};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is in this part:

```
value={{dashboard:this.state,handleChange:this.handleChange}}
```

Every time your component renders (for whatever reason), this line will create a new object. The dashboard property and handleChange property may be unchanged, but the object surrounding them is always new. That's enough that every time it renders, the value changes, and so all descendants that use the value need to be rerendered too.

You'll need to modify your code so that this object reference does not change unless you want it to. This is typically done by putting the object into the component's state.

```
class Example {
  handleChange = (what, value) => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      value: {
        ... oldState.value,
       [what]:value
      }
    });

  }

  state = {
    value: {
      dashboard: {
        // whatever you used to put in state now goes here
      },
      handleChange: this.handleChange
    }
  }

   render() {
     return (
       <DashboardContext.Provider value={this.state.value}>
         {/*...*/}
       </DashboardContext.Provider>
     )
   }
}
```

You can see mention of this in React's documentation on context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Comment: That makes sense to me. But it is still being referenced. I've changed my question to show you my current code. `handleChange` is not being called anywhere at this moment (while testing).

Comment: I noticed that the context keeps changing but the difference is that now the component is not being re-rendered (I see changes after refresh). Is this usual behavior? I would like to commit these changes by triggering `handleChange`.